# how to call Helper Method(Server Side) from JavaScript(Client)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, custom-controls

Senario :
I wanna call a Helper method from JavaScript.I produced some controls in server side such as Grid,DataTimePicker,SlideShow, ... for ASP.NET MVC.
Now, how do I invoke helper method from JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the way for invoke helper method in view(ASP.NET MVC) .
for example:

```
    namespace Component
    {
       public class HelperMethod
       {
         public static MvcHtmlString GridSort(this HtmlHelper helper,string fieldName)
         {
           //do something
         }
       }
    }
```

Code in my view:

```
    @using Component

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var message='FirstName';
        var result = "@Html.GridSort(message)";  // here is the Error
        $("div#grdUsers").html(result );
    });

    </script>

    <div id="grdUsers">
     //grid elements
    </div>
```

Now, the problem is : I can't pass JavaScript Variable(message) value to helper method(GridSort).
What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

1st Way:- make it an `ACTION returning json` - and call with `Ajax`.

```
@using Component
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var message='FirstName';
 $.ajax({
    url: '/Your Controller name /your Method name',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {message:message},
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function () {

    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert('error');
    }
});

});

</script>

<div id="grdUsers">
 //grid elements
</div>
```

2nd Way:-use `Request.QueryString["message"]`